# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function, when the function is defined in the require

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently making a wordpress plugin and I am getting this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   rate_my_stuff_calc() in
>   C:\Users\desbest\Documents\UniServerZ\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\rate-my-stuff\rate-my-stuff.php:44

However I am including the function because I have a line of code above where the function is called called

`require_once( plugins_url('rate-my-stuff/core.php' ));`

and in core.php the function is called on Line 10 of core.php with `function rate_my_stuff_calc($stars) {`

What is going on? Are functions declared in files that are required, not used in the overall plugin file?

Comment: I would suggest output/debugging the return value of `plugins_url('rate-my-stuff/core.php' )` and using that information to determine if the required path is correct.

Comment: You almost certainly want to use [`WP_PLUGIN_DIR`](https://wpseek.com/constant/wp_plugin_dir/) instead of `plugins_url`.

Comment: @leek The path is correct because when I change the file name, I get an error.

Comment: @GregSchmidt The Wordpress Codex website says it's better to use `plugins_url` and it also says not to use the constants when developing plugins or themes.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

Comment: Well `plugins_url` appears to return a URL, not a filesystem path. You might get an error when you change the file name, not because `require_once` fails, but because `plugins_url` can't find it and thus can't build a URL for it.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem. @GregSchmidt